# How I can mix column data

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a table `table_1`

```
 id     contact_id
 1         500
 5         89
 8         35
 15        458
 ...       ...
 555       38
```

how I can mix `contact_id`, result for `table_1`

```
id     contact_id
 1         35
 5         458
 8         35
 15        89
 ...       ...
 555       45
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "mix".

Comment: I fail to understand your question. Is the second table the expected result? If not, can you add the expected result?

Comment: Have you tried using a mixer?

Answer (score 1):

You can randomly assign the contact ids using variables or `row_number()` (in MySQL 8+):

```
select t1.id, tt1.contact_id
from (select t1.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from table_1 t1
     ) t1 join
     (select t1.*, row_number() over (order by rand()) as seqnum
      from table_1 t1
     ) tt1
     on t1.seqnum = tt1.seqnum;
```

Without much difficulty (but more typing), this can be transformed to use variables in earlier versions.

You can also incorporate this into an `update` statement, if you want to shuffle the values permanently.

EDIT:

I think you want:

```
update table1 t1 join
       (select t1.id, tt1.contact_id
        from (select t1.*, (@rn1 := @rn1 + 1) as seqnum
              from (select * table_1 order by id) t1 cross join
                   (select @rn1 := 0) params
             ) t1 join
             (select t1.*, (@rn2 := @rn2 + 1) as seqnum
              from (select * from table_1 order by rand()) t1 cross join
                   (select @rn2 := 0) params
             ) tt1
             on t1.seqnum = tt1.seqnum
       ) tt1
       on tt1.id = t1.id
    set t1.contact_id = tt1.contact_id;
```

Comment: I have have a maria db 5.6 and window function not working on

Comment: @TigranShahnazaryan Right, but what do you mean by **mix**? Please respond.

Comment: @The Impaler I want to mix contact_id ordering